# sbt local repository and resolvers

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm having issues publishing artifacts from one project to a file based repository and loading them into another seperate project.

I can publish using this setting on my library projects

```
ThisBuild/publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File( "c:/repository" ))(Resolver.mavenStylePatterns))

publish/skip := true
```

I can also publish using this setting

```
ThisBuild/publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File( "c:/repository" ))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns))
```

when I try to reference this from another project (with a subproject) I simply replicate the setting but applying it to a resolver.

```
ThisBuild/resolvers += Resolver.file("file",  new File( "c:/repository" ))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

same settings...

so we force a reimport into intellij and...

```
[warn]  module not found: wonschemacore#wonschemacore_2.12;1.6
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\m_r_n\.ivy2\local\wonschemacore\wonschemacore_2.12\1.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/wonschemacore/wonschemacore_2.12/1.6/wonschemacore_2.12-1.6.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\m_r_n\.sbt\preloaded\wonschemacore\wonschemacore_2.12\1.6\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/m_r_n/.sbt/preloaded/wonschemacore/wonschemacore_2.12/1.6/wonschemacore_2.12-1.6.pom
[warn] ==== file: tried
[warn]   c:\repository\wonschemacore\wonschemacore_2.12\1.6\ivys\ivy.xml
```

now, the last warning looks promising (for sbt!) so we look for this folder and file and find it doesnt exist!

so for some reason the publish doesnt seem to be creating these "ivys" files.

If I use Maven style,

```
ThisBuild/resolvers += Resolver.file("file",  new File( "c:/repository" ))(Resolver.mavenStylePatterns)
```

then the client app fails to even "try" my additional resolver;

```
[warn]  module not found: wonschemacore#wonschemacore_2.12;1.5
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\m_r_n\.ivy2\local\wonschemacore\wonschemacore_2.12\1.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/wonschemacore/wonschemacore_2.12/1.5/wonschemacore_2.12-1.5.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\m_r_n\.sbt\preloaded\wonschemacore\wonschemacore_2.12\1.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/m_r_n/.sbt/preloaded/wonschemacore/wonschemacore_2.12/1.5/wonschemacore_2.12-1.5.pom
[warn] ==== file: tried
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

so both formats don't work for me.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I THINK I've solved it

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1917

amazingly you seem to have to tell sbt to not publish maven style seperately from "publishTo" setting.

```
ThisBuild/publishMavenStyle := false
```

Ivy vs Maven is not something I understand at all...so I find this all slightly baffling.

I assume that the default publishing style is Maven, and using IvyStylePatterns is simply a strategy for naming files, not the implementation of the repository.

P.S.

I still don't understand why the MavenStyle resolvers just didnt seem to find the MavenStyle repositories, but for the moment I can carry on, IvyStyle.